# PHP - Inner join table has Rows with same Id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to Inner Join a table to other

Table1 : Songs

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ Id ║ Title ║ Artist ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 10 ║ abc   ║ acc    ║
║ 11 ║ dfg   ║ rtty   ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

Table2 : Files

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ filename ║ Version ║ song_id ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ 125.mp3  ║ version1║      10 ║
║  2 ║ 45.mp3   ║ version2║      10 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

(song_id -》from table1)

I want to display them in table Inline like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Title ║ Artist ║ version1 ║ version2 ║
╠═══════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ abc   ║ acc    ║ 125.mp3  ║  45.mp3  ║
╚═══════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I tried this

```sql
 SELECT * FROM songs 
    INNER JOIN files on 
    files.song_id = songs.id
```

After fetch it i tried to put them in arrays
Like this

```php
$array[$row ['id']] [$row ['version']] = $row['filename']
```

But it gives me line foreach file not in same row! How can I do that?

Comment: I recommend you add some more sample data to show what you mean by "Every song has many files and the files has versions", perhaps change "Clean" and "Dirty" to clearer names or explain what they mean, and give examples of the output you got vs the output you want

Comment: I want them just like that example that i need . I've changed the names of the versions to be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```sql
SELECT *,
  (SELECT filename FROM files f WHERE f.song_id = s.id AND f.version = 'version1') AS version1,
  (SELECT filename FROM files f WHERE f.song_id = s.id AND f.version = 'version2') AS version2

FROM songs s

WHERE s.id = 10
```

You can check result online here :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a41db3/14

```
╔════╦═══════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ title ║ artist ║ version1 ║ version2 ║
╠════╬═══════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 10 ║ abc   ║ acc    ║ 125.mp3  ║ 45.mp3   ║
╚════╩═══════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going to need to join to the `files` table twice, once for the *Clean* version and once for the *Dirty* - and since it's the same table each time, you'll need to alias it. Try this:

```
SELECT * 

FROM songs

INNER JOIN files AS cf
    ON cf.song_id = songs.song_id
    AND cf.version = 'Clean'

INNER JOIN files AS df
    ON cf.song_id = songs.song_id
    AND cf.version = 'Dirty'
```